# Can't connect to Neo

Tags: macos, neo4j, docker

I've installed Docker on OSX and downloaded the neo image.  when I run it (using the args in the home page of the image), everything seems to work, but the last lines of the log indicate something like:

> 00:20:39.662 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started
>   @4761ms 2015-10-05 00:20:39.663+0000 INFO  [API] Server started on:
>   http://022b5f3a38fc:7474/ 2015-10-05 00:20:39.663+0000 INFO  [API]
>   Remote interface ready and available at [http://022b5f3a38fc:7474/]

which seem odd and attempting to connect my browser to either http://localhost:7474/ or the indicated http://022b5f3a38fc:7474/ results in an error

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the IP address of the docker VM, which you can determine with this command:

```
docker-machine inspect default | grep IPAddress
```

The default IP address is 192.168.99.100

So depending on which port you exposed when running the Neo4j docker container you can access the Neo4j browser at:

```
http://192.168.99.100:7474
```

or

```
http://192.168.99.100:8474
```

Port 8474 is the the binding specified by this command:

```
docker run -i -t --rm --name neo4j -v $HOME/neo4j-data:/data -p 8474:7474 neo4j/neo4j
```

which is the example given in the documentation [here](http://neo4j.com/developer/docker/)

Comment: ah! I knew I'd read somewhere about the VM's IP.  thanks for clearing that up.  it works. +1

Comment: one other note: seems like Neo needs to figure out a better way to display the operating url